# How to read csv row by row and prevent skipping lines

Tags: python, json, pandas

Have this as data from a csv as rawdata coming in by REST api.

```
serial-number;device-identification;created;value-data-count;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,0;duration-since-last-readout,second(s),inst-value,0,0,0;op-time,second(s),inst-value,0,0,0;enhanced-id,,inst-value,0,0,0;model/version,,inst-value,0,0,0;date start-date/time-of,,inst-value,0,0,0;error-flags-dev-spec,,inst-value,0,0,0
0016025738;01234559;2022-06-29 16:02:00;00;1600,359;24;6170801;1234559;DN 20;2017-02-20 00:00:00;256
serial-number;device-identification;created;value-data-count;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,0;datetime,,inst-value,0,0,0;date,,inst-value,0,0,1;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,1;date future-value,,inst-value,0,0,1;fabrication-no,,inst-value,0,0,0;date,,inst-value,0,0,2;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,2;date,,inst-value,0,0,3;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,3;date,,inst-value,0,0,4;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,4;date,,inst-value,0,0,5;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,5;date,,inst-value,0,0,6;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,6;date,,inst-value,0,0,7;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,7;date,,inst-value,0,0,8;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,8;date,,inst-value,0,0,9;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,9;date,,inst-value,0,0,10;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,10;date,,inst-value,0,0,11;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,11;date,,inst-value,0,0,12;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,12;date,,inst-value,0,0,13;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,13;manufacturer-specific,,inst-value,0,0,0
0016025738;04950544;2022-06-29 16:02:00;00;1359,662;2022-06-29 17:09:00;2021-06-29 00:00:00;1359,662;2022-06-29 00:00:00;1111117;2022-01-31 00:00:00;1359,662;2022-02-28 00:00:00;1359,662;2022-03-31 00:00:00;1359,662;2022-04-30 00:00:00;1359,662;2022-05-31 00:00:00;1359,662;2021-06-30 00:00:00;1359,662;2021-07-31 00:00:00;1359,662;2021-08-31 00:00:00;1359,662;2021-09-30 00:00:00;1359,662;2021-10-31 00:00:00;1359,662;2021-11-30 00:00:00;1359,662;2021-12-31 00:00:00;1359,662;010001
```

And need to bring it into json format.

What I already tried:

```
rawdata2 = StringIO(rawdata.decode().replace('\t',''))
df = pd.read_csv(rawdata2, sep=';',  error_bad_lines=False)

newlist = df.to_json(orient='index')                                                           
log.msg("newlist is: ", newlist)
```

The first line is process correct, but not the second. This brings an error like:

```
b'Skipping line 3: expected 11 fields, saw 35\nSkipping line 4: expected 11 fields, saw 35\n'
```

I know that read_csv reads the first line and guess every other row has similar columns. But in my example, there can be more or less in each row.

So basically the goal is to prevent that lines are skipped. I need every line processed into json.

I tried and thought to read the file row by row, means iterate over the indexes, but I don't know how to write this part of code.

Comment: Is it always one line of header and one line of data? In that case, treat it as a stream of separate 2-line csv files.

Comment: As data comes in one package, it isn't that easy to split into several csv's. There could be some hundreds of datasets in one package. but thanks for your proposition

Comment: reading line by line is literally splitting it. So it should be easy. good luck. Ad-hoc is probably good because the format is not quite csv anyway (?) with both , and ; separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read line by line (one line of headings and one line of content), using the longest headings as the complete headings：

```
a = """
serial-number;device-identification;created;value-data-count;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,0;duration-since-last-readout,second(s),inst-value,0,0,0;op-time,second(s),inst-value,0,0,0;enhanced-id,,inst-value,0,0,0;model/version,,inst-value,0,0,0;date start-date/time-of,,inst-value,0,0,0;error-flags-dev-spec,,inst-value,0,0,0
0016025738;01234559;2022-06-29 16:02:00;00;1600,359;24;6170801;1234559;DN 20;2017-02-20 00:00:00;256
serial-number;device-identification;created;value-data-count;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,0;datetime,,inst-value,0,0,0;date,,inst-value,0,0,1;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,1;date future-value,,inst-value,0,0,1;fabrication-no,,inst-value,0,0,0;date,,inst-value,0,0,2;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,2;date,,inst-value,0,0,3;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,3;date,,inst-value,0,0,4;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,4;date,,inst-value,0,0,5;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,5;date,,inst-value,0,0,6;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,6;date,,inst-value,0,0,7;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,7;date,,inst-value,0,0,8;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,8;date,,inst-value,0,0,9;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,9;date,,inst-value,0,0,10;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,10;date,,inst-value,0,0,11;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,11;date,,inst-value,0,0,12;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,12;date,,inst-value,0,0,13;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,13;manufacturer-specific,,inst-value,0,0,0
0016025738;04950544;2022-06-29 16:02:00;00;1359,662;2022-06-29 17:09:00;2021-06-29 00:00:00;1359,662;2022-06-29 00:00:00;1111117;2022-01-31 00:00:00;1359,662;2022-02-28 00:00:00;1359,662;2022-03-31 00:00:00;1359,662;2022-04-30 00:00:00;1359,662;2022-05-31 00:00:00;1359,662;2021-06-30 00:00:00;1359,662;2021-07-31 00:00:00;1359,662;2021-08-31 00:00:00;1359,662;2021-09-30 00:00:00;1359,662;2021-10-31 00:00:00;1359,662;2021-11-30 00:00:00;1359,662;2021-12-31 00:00:00;1359,662;010001
"""


def solution(text):
    res = []
    items = [item.strip().split(";") for item in text.split("\n") if item.strip()]
    for i in range(0, len(items), 2):
        title, data = items[i], items[i+1]
        res.append(dict(zip(title, data)))
    res = sorted(res, key=len)
    for item in res[:-1]:
        for item2, val2 in res[-1].items():
            if item2 not in item:
                item[item2] = None
    return res


print(json.dumps(solution(a)))
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine until a key is not twice in the data package. If a key is twice, dicts ignores the second. This is not surprising.

Comment: Here a dataset where a key volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,0; is twice.

a = """
serial-number;device-identification;created;value-data-count;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,0;datetime,,inst-value,0,0,0;date,,inst-value,0,0,1;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,0;date future-value,,inst-value,0,0,1;fabrication-no,,inst-value,0,0,0;date,,inst-value,0,0,2;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,0;0016025738;04950544;2022-06-29 16:02:00;00;1359,662;2022-06-29 17:09:00;2021-06-29 00:00:00;1359,662;2022-06-29 00:00:00;1111117;2022-01-31 00:00:00;1359
"""

Comment: How could it be handled then? maybe by adding an index to the duplciated key or by adding a list as value for that key? @maya